# How or where to find Anypoint MQ /messages/locks?

Tags: mule, mule4, anypoint-mq

```
Log : Connection unexpectedly closed from PATCH <https://mq-us-west-1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/3360c974-31ba-49b4-ffd4-ce6cb8afce0d/environments/b1fb25d8-4482-4357-b3f0-b00b52cc705a/destinations/sample-Q/messages/locks.
```

Where can I obtain this path "**destinations/sample-Q/messages/locks**" in AnyPoint Platform ?

checked platform level logs but no luck

Comment: There are no Anypoint Platform level logs if you are referring to that. There  are per application Mule logs in Runtime Manager. Are you referring to the application logs?

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of Mule 4 and it is not a file path or folder. The URL is part of the [REST API of Anypoint MQ](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-apis). This is the documentation for that specific endpoint: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/anypoint-mq-broker/minor/1.0/console/method/%23510/

Note that `sample-Q` is a destination name created in your environment, not a part of the API.